# Split a multi-line string at the beginning of each line using RegularExpression

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to replicate the following code using [`RegularExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) instead of [`StartOfLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartOfLine.html):

```
In[1]:= StringSplit["line1\nline2\nline3",StartOfLine]//InputForm

Out[1]={"line1\n", "line2\n", "line3"}
```

#### Failed Attempt:

```
In[34]:= StringSplit["line1\nline2\nline3",RegularExpression["^/m"]]//InputForm

Out[34]= {"line1\nline2\nline3"}
```

How can I get this to work using Mathematica's flavor of regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mathematica, you set the Regex options with prefix notation.

For multiline mode, you need to prepend your regex expression with "(?m)"

This is in the Details section of [`RegularExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html):

[image]

```
StringSplit["line1\nline2\nline3", RegularExpression["(?m)^"]] // InputForm
```